# React-Intl Changing language does not change the translations

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I have a small issue with React-Intl.

When the app is loaded, the translations are ok, but when I change the language, i18nConfig is changed but the translations are not updated.

I tried several things but I can't make it work.

App.js :

```
let i18nConfig = {
  locale: navigator.language.split(/[-_]/)[0],
  messages: getMessagesFromLang(navigator.language.split(/[-_]/)[0])
};

function getMessagesFromLang(lang) {
  switch (lang) {
    case "fr":
      return locale_fr;
    case "en":
      return locale_en;
    default:
      return locale_en;
  }
}

function onChangeLanguage(lang) {
  switch (lang) {
    case "fr": i18nConfig.messages = locale_fr; break;
    case "en": i18nConfig.messages = locale_en; break;
    default: i18nConfig.messages = locale_en; break;
  }
  i18nConfig.locale = lang;
}

function getCurrentLang() {
  return i18nConfig.locale;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <IntlProvider key={i18nConfig.locale} locale={i18nConfig.locale} messages={i18nConfig.messages}>
      <Content onChangeLanguage={onChangeLanguage} getCurrentLang={getCurrentLang} />
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

Content.js :

```
const options = [{ value: "en", label: "English" },{ value: "fr", label: "Français" }];    
export default class Content extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption }, () =>
      console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption)
    );

    this.props.onChangeLanguage(selectedOption.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <span><FormattedMessage id="app.content.link.rules" defaultMessage="Rules" /></span>
        <Select value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} options={options} />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Intl how to switch locale and messages from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635584/react-intl-how-to-switch-locale-and-messages-from-variable)

Comment: That's exactly what I used but the texts aren't changing

Comment: Have you tried putting `onChangeLanguage` inside of App scope?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try this

Comment: Same behaviour, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so basically react isn't aware of that change, I made some changes so that react would know when its changed:

```
export default function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = React.useState(i18nConfig.locale) // keeps state of lang in App
  function onChangeLanguage(lang) {
    setLang(lang) // changes the lang when selec value changes
  }
  return (
    <IntlProvider key={lang} locale={lang} messages={getMessagesFromLang(lang)}>
      /* note how props are changed in order to stay updated */
      <Content onChangeLanguage={onChangeLanguage} getCurrentLang={getCurrentLang} />
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: How does React.useState works, plz ? I'm kinda new to react

Comment: useState returns an array of the variable itself and setter for it. you can find out more on [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)